# search a string in an array of strings

Tags: c, ansi-c

I keep getting bad pointers. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
int SearchString( char* arr[], char* key, int size )
{
int n;
for ( n = 0; n < size; ++n ) {
    if ( strcmp(arr[n], key) ) { 
        return n;
    } 
} 
return -1;

}
```

---

```
char str[][16] = { "mov","cmp","add","sub","lea","not","clr","inc","dec","jmp","bne","red","jrn","psr","rts","stop"};

    if(SearchString(str,"word",16) == -1){  return FALSE;}
```

Comment: Your `str` is an array of 16 strings (the compiler created the 16 automatically) each of which can hold 15+1 characters (that you specified as the 2nd dimension). You may save a few bytes with `char str[][4] = {"mov", "cmp", ...};` and `if (SearchString(str, "word", sizeof str / sizeof *str) == -1) /* ... */;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't tell where your `word` originates from. You probably want to `if (!strcmp(arr[n],key)) return n;` (the reverse). And the type of array is probably not what you want. Try

```
const char *str[] = { "mov",.... };
```

instead. You have an array of arrays of characters and pass it where you actually expect an array of pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Change `char str[][16]` to `char *str[16]` (or only `char *str[]`).

Also, `strcmp` returns zero when the strings are equal, so you want this instead:

```
if ( strcmp(arr[n], key) == 0 ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp()` returns *zero* if strings are equal! Your test should be `if (!strcmp(...))`

Also, consider using `strncmp()`.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is passed as char **ar which is not correct.

One of the alternatives is changing protopype to:

`int SearchString( char arr[][16], char* key, int size )`
to get the expected behaviour.