# How to check if a string is in an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays

How to write below code in C? Also: is there any built in function for checking length of an array?

**Python Code**

```
x = ['ab', 'bc' , 'cd']
s = 'ab'

if s in x:
  //Code
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848940/search-a-string-in-an-array-of-strings

Comment: This post is Python translating to C, so it can't be a duplicate of a question posed in C.

Comment: @CareyGregory Why not? The OP has to rewrite the whole program to C, the original Python code is not helpful.

Comment: Yes it is helpful. It specifies exactly what task the questioner is looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no function for checking length of array in C. However, if the array is declared in the same scope as where you want to check, you can do the following

```
int len = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);
```

You have to iterate through x and do strcmp on each element of array x, to check if s is the same as one of the elements of x.

```
char * x [] = { "ab", "bc", "cd" };
char * s = "ab";
int len = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);
int i;

for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    if(!strcmp(x[i], s))
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @CareyGregory - my original post wasn't incorrect - this way isn't a function. And it works only if the array is declared in the same scope.

Comment: I didn't say your post was incorrect; it wasn't.  It was simply less than it could have been, but you fixed it.  So all is well, yes?  :-)

Comment: This is not exactly what OP wants as the conditional code would execute multiple times if the target string appears more than once in the array of strings, right?

Answer (score 12):

Something like this??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *x[] = {"ab", "bc", "cd", 0};
    char *s = "ab";
    int i = 0;
    while(x[i]) {
        if(strcmp(x[i], s) == 0) {
            printf("Gotcha!\n");
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible C implementation for Python's `in` method could be

```
#include <string.h>

int in(char **arr, int len, char *target) {
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(strncmp(arr[i], target, strlen(target)) == 0) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  char *x[3] = { "ab", "bc", "cd" };
  char *s = "ab";

  if(in(x, 3, s)) {
    // code
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Note that the use of `strncmp` instead of `strcmp` allows for easier comparison of string with different sizes. More about the both of them in their [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncmp.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is a function for finding string length. It is `strlen` from `string.h`

And then you could use the `strcmp` from the same header to compare strings, just as the other answers say.