# Check if input string exists in array of strings in C

Tags: c, string, search, input

I'm new to C and I'm trying to solve a problem.

I want to ask for user to insert 5 colors in an array but want to check if string exists on the existing array (allowed colors), or not  before it is added.
I've tried with `strcmp` and some other ways but can figure out how to do it.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *colors[] = {
    "green",
    "red",
    "blue",
    "yellow",
    "brown",
    "white",
    "black"
};
int n = 5, i, num, size = 7;
char input[5][7];

int main() {
    char *str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

    printf("Add 5 colors:\n ");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s", input[i]);
        strcpy(str, input[i]);

        if (strcmp(colors[i], str) == 0) {
            printf("Exists!\n");
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d %s\n", 1 + i, input[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: August Karlstrom, thanks. Iǘe donne that.

Comment: There is still a syntax error in your code. You also need to include the required header files.

Comment: I have compiled with 2 diferent compilers and Iḿ getting no error. Can you please tell me what is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string is in an array of strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677890/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-in-an-array-of-strings-in-c)

Comment: Hey Robert Harvey, yes it helps but I still didnt figure out why strcmp fails. just changed the code here to what iǘe tried. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Bruno Your code had a missing brace but I see that it has been corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a nested loop to compare the input with every string in the reference array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *colors[7] = {
    "green",
    "red",
    "blue",
    "yellow",
    "brown",
    "white",
    "black",
};

int main() {
    int n, i, j, num, size = 7;
    char input[5][8];

    printf("Add 5 colors:\n ");

    n = 0;
    while (n < 5) {
        if (scanf("%7s", input[n]) != 1)
            break;

        for (int j = 0; j < 7; i++) {
            if (strcmp(input[n], colors[j]) == 0) {
                printf("Exists!\n");
                n++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d %s\n", 1 + i, input[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```